# Fastest way to hash 3D integer coordinates in c++

Tags: c++, hash

I have a gameworld divided into sections where every section is addressed as 3 integer coordinates. There is an origin in the world at 0,0,0 and the coordinates can be negative.

I access the sections using unordered_maps with a hash function implemented for those 3D integer coordinates.

Now I wonder, what the fastest way which still produces a low amount of collisions given than only a small region of nearby sectors are likely to be loaded in memory at any given time.

Right now I use this hash function:

```
size_t x = coord.x;
x = (x | (x << 32)) & 0xFFFF00000000FFFF;
x = (x | (x << 16)) & 0x00FF0000FF0000FF;
x = (x | (x << 8))  & 0xF00F00F00F00F00F;
x = (x | (x << 4))  & 0x30C30C30C30C30C3;
x = (x | (x << 2))  & 0x9249249249249249;

size_t y = coord.y;
y = (y | (y << 32)) & 0xFFFF00000000FFFF;
y = (y | (y << 16)) & 0x00FF0000FF0000FF;
y = (y | (y << 8))  & 0xF00F00F00F00F00F;
y = (y | (y << 4))  & 0x30C30C30C30C30C3;
y = (y | (y << 2))  & 0x9249249249249249;

size_t z = coord.z;
z = (z | (z << 32)) & 0xFFFF00000000FFFF;
z = (z | (z << 16)) & 0x00FF0000FF0000FF;
z = (z | (z << 8))  & 0xF00F00F00F00F00F;
z = (z | (z << 4))  & 0x30C30C30C30C30C3;
z = (z | (z << 2))  & 0x9249249249249249;
return x | (y << 1) | (z << 2);
```

Which is a simple bit interleave/z-order function. It is very good when it comes to avoiding nearby collisions but since this hash function is still called a lot of times in my code base (it consists of 5% of the execution time) it could possibly be improved.

Are there any faster and still good enough ways than this one?